# javascript object assignment expression - comparison

Tags: javascript, expression

Suppose we've got an optional parameter of a function which can come as `undefined`. Is there any difference between

```
options || (options = {});
```

and

```
options = options || {};
```

? If there is none, which one do you find better (I mean faster or more readable)? The question is - **which one would you use to implement optional parameters** in javascript?

Comment: What is the context of these lines?

Comment: @RoyiNamir your edition causes syntax error...

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz yes sorry. I was going to fix that( after I thought there was a missing brace) . thanks for correcting.

Comment: I think the 2nd one is more readable.

Comment: @JNF I've edited my question. The context is that you're inside a function and options parameter is optional - and how would you handle it?

Answer (score 0):

Those exact 2 lines are different :

in the first one its an expression which do nothing with options ( if it is not defined) while the other is a statement.

Comment: OK, yeah, I know that - but their effect is the same (I think so). And the question is do you prefer one of them over another?

Comment: This is wrong. Firstly, a raw expression is still a statement. Secondly, the first snippet still assigns an empty object to `options` if it is falsy.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz If `options` isn't defined (due to not being passed), it will be assigned a value of `{}`. You can confirm this [here](http://jsbin.com/aWecAxE/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Logically, they both are the same.

```
options || (options = {});
```

If `options` is a Truthy value, then it will short circuit and will not go to the next part. If it is a Falsy value, it goes to the next part where and empty object is created and assigned to `options`.

```
options = options || {};
```

The same thing, first right hand side is evaluated. If `options` is Truthy, it will be assigned as it is to `options`, if it is Falsy, an empty object is created and that is assigned to `options`.

**Note:** If `options` is an optional parameter of a function, and if it can accept other Falsy values, even if the user passes a Falsy value, intentionally, like `false`, 0, `null`, it will still use an empty object